# c# cplex api setup clarification steps

Tags: c#, .net, cplex

I am trying to start using the c#.net api for ibm cplex v12.6. However, I have trouble in the installation:

IBM page is telling me i need to set the compiler and linker:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/Csharp/prerequisites.html

but what exactly do i need to do?

I am also confused by visual studio versions: is the community 2013 ok?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing on that page is telling you to set the compiler and linker.

Comment: With regards to which Visual Studio versions are supported, see the [detailed system requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100).

Answer (score 0):

Just run the CPLEX installer and take the default options. It will install everything you need to use CPLEX with Visual Studio (and a lot more as well), and should be compatible with any recent version of VS. Only real decision is whether to install the 32 or 64 bit version (or both). It'll put a mountain of stuff in somewhere like 'C:\Program files\IBM' but you can ignore most of it when working with C# and .Net

When I am working with Visual Studio and C#, I pretty much only ever use stuff in one folder such as:

C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1271\cplex\bin\x64_win64

Obviously you need to have a compiler and linker to do stuff with C#, and Visual Studio is the obvious choice. I have used many combinations of versions over the years (currently using 64-bit CPLEX 12.4, 12.5.1, 12.6.3 and 12.7.1 on various projects, with VS2008, VS2010 and VS2015, both pro and community editions) so I can't see why you would have a problem.

Comment: I thought that was the problem mainly because I've been following examples on IBM knowledge center step by step, but everytime i run any of the examples, they just either run correctly without giving me any output though, either not finding the output bin.

Maybe I have other issues I'm not aware of. I'll keep looking, thanks anyway.